# How to use Data Binding with custom view Android

Tags: android

This is my custom view .xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.viewModel.ViewModel" />

</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.views.MyView
        app:length="@{viewModel.codeLenght}"
        app:success_color="@drawable/border_green_fill_white"
        app:width="@dimen/icon_size_huge" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my view:

```
class MyView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr){

init {
    val styles = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CodeTextView)
    styleEditTexts(styles, attrs)
    styles.recycle()
}

private fun styleEditTexts(styles: TypedArray, attrs: AttributeSet?) {
    length = styles.getInt(R.styleable.AttrView_length, DEFAULT_LENGTH)
    generateViews(styles, attrs)
}

@BindingAdapter("app:length")
fun setLength(view: CodeTextView, size: Int) {
    view.length = size
}
```

How can I obtain the length value from ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain `ViewModel` class inside `MyView` in the same way as inside `Activity`/`Fragment` using `context`.

`ViewModelProvider(context as YourActivity)[ViewModel::class.java]`